# Where is windows 10 start layout xml file located in version 1803?

Tags: windows, start-menu, file-location

Is it possible to find and edit windows 10 version 1803 start layout without exporting & importing, and if yes, where this xml file can be found?

Comment: You have to export the layout in order to generate the file then make the modifications and import it and apply it to all users.

Comment: @Ramhound So no way to see it without exporting I assume?

Comment: To my knowledge, there isn't a layout file unless you export one.